# Get correct paragraph indenting in `solution` environment of `exam` documentclass

Tags: indentation, exam

MWE:

```
\documentclass{exam}
   \setlength\parindent{100pt}

\printanswers
\begin{document}

   \begin{questions}
      \question Please help me.
         \begin{parts}
            \part Will this produce correctly indented paragraphs?


        \begin{solution}
           This is the first paragraph of the solution lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. \par
           This is the second paragraph dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est.
        \end{solution}

        \part No difference with blank lines?
        \begin{solution}
           This is the first paragraph of the solution lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.

           This is the second paragraph dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est.
        \end{solution}

     \end{parts}
   \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The paragraphs of the `solution`s are not properly indented. How can I get paragraphs to indent correctly in the `solution` environment?

I've tried setting the indent length, and I've tried using both `par` and a blank line to get a paragraph. I've also had a look at the documentation for the class, but I didn't see anything that adressed my question.

Comment: If you mean indentation inside the `solution` environment, you may need to set the length there. I don't use the class, so maybe there's a class-specific way to do it. If not, then `\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\setlength\parindent{100pt}}` may do the trick.

Comment: This fix works! :D But please forgive me if I wait for another answer that may be more elegant or that doesn't require loading more packages. :) Alternatively, feel free to write this as an answer and if nothing else comes up I'll select it as an answer. ;)

Comment: Maybe it's worth an upvote, but if an `exam`-specific answer is given, that's probably worth the checkmark....

Answer (score 3):

One way to adjust (globally) the spacing of the `solution` environment is to use `etoolbox`, which provides the `\AtBeginEnvironment` command. So:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\setlength{\parindent}{100pt}}

\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Please help me.

  \begin{parts}
  \part Will this produce correctly indented paragraphs?

    \begin{solution}
    This is the first paragraph of the solution lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.

    This is the second paragraph dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est dolorum est.
    \end{solution}

  \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice.  This is needed because the questions, parts, subparts, and subsubparts environments are all implemented as LaTeX list environments, which set the parindent to 0pt.

Comment: It's nice to know the reason why!